# Execute a command after uninstall

Tags: inno-setup

I need my uninstall to run a command *after* it's removed the files it has installed.
[UninstallRun] is no use as I understand it runs BEFORE files are removed.
I kind of need a "postuninstall" flag.

Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish the above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See "[Uninstall Event Functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents)" in the documentation. You can use for instance [`CurUninstallStepChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged) when 'CurUninstallStep' is 'usPostUninstall'.

Comment: @eyoopmeduck - if that solved your problem, you should accept the answer - use the big tick / check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Oops - sorry - this is my first question. Regards Mark.

Comment: No worries - I could see from your profile you were new to the site.

Answer (score 5):

In the same way there is a [Run] section, Inno allows to you to define an [[UninstallRun]](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) section to specify which files of your Installer package should be executed on unistall.

For example:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: {app}\Scripts\DeleteWindowsService.bat; Flags: runhidden;
```

Alternatively, solution proposed by @Sertac Akyuz, which makes use of event functions can be used for tunning a bit more unistalling actions. Here is an example of the usage of CurUninstallStepChanged function among other related functions.

https://github.com/HeliumProject/InnoSetup/blob/master/Examples/UninstallCodeExample1.iss

```
; -- UninstallCodeExample1.iss --
;
; This script shows various things you can achieve using a [Code] section for Uninstall

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Code]
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := MsgBox('InitializeUninstall:' #13#13 'Uninstall is initializing. Do you really want to start Uninstall?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = idYes;
  if Result = False then
    MsgBox('InitializeUninstall:' #13#13 'Ok, bye bye.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
  MsgBox('DeinitializeUninstall:' #13#13 'Bye bye!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usUninstall:
      begin
        MsgBox('CurUninstallStepChanged:' #13#13 'Uninstall is about to start.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
        // ...insert code to perform pre-uninstall tasks here...
      end;
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
        MsgBox('CurUninstallStepChanged:' #13#13 'Uninstall just finished.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        // ...insert code to perform post-uninstall tasks here...
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The OP had explicitly stated that `[UninstallRun]` was not suitable due to the installation order.